# Can we differentiate if point charge is rotating or not?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, angular-velocity

First, sorry for the low level English and physics knowledge.

Point charge. If point charge is not possible, let me use ball charge.

The ball charge is same in all directions. (Symmetric)
It's maybe metal ball with static charge.

If it is only spinning but not translating, is there change in electric field around the charge?

If spinning, but it is same every side. How can we know or we can't know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throughout I'll assume the charge has no translational motion.

### Ball Charge

This case is straightforward. A rotating ball of charge produces the exact same electric field as a non-rotating ball of charge. This is because the electric field depends on the charge density and the charge density of a rotating ball of charge is not changing as a function of time.

However, a rotating ball of charge produces a magnetic field (because moving charges -- i.e. currents -- create magnetic fields) while a stationary ball of charge produces no magnetic field. So, if you can sense magnetic fields then you could determine whether a ball of charge is spinning or not.

### Point Charge

This case is a little more complicated because it is a bit tricky to say what it means for a point charge to be rotating. Normally rotation involves velocity of a body relative to a fixed axis but if a particle  is point particle it has no spatial extant and no part of it can really be moving relative to an axis..

However, within quantum physics and quantum field theory we are aware of particles which, to the best of our knowledge are point particles, but also exhibit properties similar to angular momentum. The property similar to angular momentum is of course particle spin.

Now to the question at hand. Just like the ball charge, a point charge with spin produces the exact same electric field as a point charge without spin. Again this is because the electric field only depends on the charge distribution which is the same for both.

However, again, just like the ball charge case, a point charge with spin will produce a magnetic field while a point charge without spin will produce no magnetic field. The math in this case is a little more complicated than in the classical ball charge case but the basic physics is similar. See especially [G-factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-factor_(physics)).

### Summary:

Stationary and spinning charges produce the same electric field

Spinning charges produce magnetic fields while electric fields don't.

Comment: Thanks! You know exactly what I wanted know

Comment: Spin is an intrinsic property of the particles which has nothing to do with classical spin.

Comment: Quantum spin can be traded with classical angular momentum while conserving total angular momentum. Both classical spinning charges and quantum point particles with spin create magnetic fields. I would say there are enough similarities between classical angular momentum and quantum spin that it is unwarranted to say "Spin... has nothing to do with classical spin". Of course there are differences, some of which I point out, but I think the similarities are much more important when answering this question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, You can't assume the point charge to be spinning.

Now if you are assuming the charged sphere to be rotating. You can still use Gauss's law to obtain the electric field. It's easy to see the angular speed of sphere will not affect the electric field. Now, If the sphere is rotating, there will be a surface current and thus there will be a Magnetic field.